# CS50 Mario (More Comfortable) Error. why are my Pyramids not Aligning properly?

Tags: c, cs50

what is wrong with my code? when I run both of them individually, the Pyramids align properly but after I remove the //sign to run them together, my pyramids get screwed up. Please what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int H;
    //Ask for Height of Pyramid
    do {
        H = get_int("Height Please: ");

    } while (H<=0 || H > 8);
    for (int x=0;  x < H; x++)
        {
        // Create left Aligned Pyramid
           for (int y = 0; y < H; y++)
                   if (x + y < H - 1)
                      printf(" "); 
                  else 
                      printf("#");
                      printf("\n");

        // Create Right Aligned Pyramid
           for (int y = 0; y < H; y++)
                if (x-y>=0) 

                       printf(" "); //Space in Between both Pyramids
                       printf("#");

                 else 
                      printf(" ");                  
                     printf("\n");          
    }

}
```

Comment: Use curly braces.  Your indenting is misleading and probably the cause of your errors.

Comment: In fact, this code shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It does compile when I comment out "printf(" ");//space in between both pyramids" line but when I run it again without the comment, it doesn't. I am new to this so I appreciate any feedback

Comment: As I said, use curly braces.  Your `for-loop`s and `if-else`s are not encapsulated the way your indenting would imply.

Comment: Yes, the two printf lines break the syntax of C. You get a "else without if" for the second else, don't you? Listen to Christians advice. And follow a few tutorials on basic C, especially control structures.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Turn your comments into an answer please. OP did not yet get that you have solved the problem. (Well, probably solved. I did not test. Please you do so.)

Comment: @Yunnosch My comments are really just a start here.  Throwing in a few curly braces will not result in anything that looks like two pyramids.

Comment: please see the post above. both pyramids have been created by isolating the two main codes seen above (you can test to see for yourself). I was just having issues putting the pyramid's side by side

Comment: Side note: This code is compiling by luck alone. If your compiler isn't returning warnings to you when you compile this code, then you should look into making it do so. Using GCC it would look something like `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic`.

Comment: I updated with proper indenting and curly braces. What i had in the code prior was not accurate. Please see now and hopefully, it'll be easier to point me in the right direction. Both my pyramids are created one on top and the other on the bottom and are both properly aligned. I just need help getting them to be side by side with the space in between. Thanks

Comment: Editing your question to incorporate (partially, incorrectly and unhelpfully) parts of the answer you got is not appreciated. On top of that, changing the actual focus of the question from "compiler errors" to "incorrect output" is considered a "moving-target" question and NOT appreciated. Please make a separate question on how to make to patterns next to each other instead of on top of each other. I will return your question to the state it got an answer in.

Comment: I am not sure what exctly your post is pointing to but as you can see, the code was updated way before the response was posted. I would definitely appreciate not jumping into conclusions here. The updates made to the code were done before the final response was posted by @ChristianGibbons which I greatly appreciate but please see facts first before making conclusions. If you read my initial question you would see I mentioned the issue of my pyramids not aligning side by side, not my code not compling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start with the first problem: You really should be using curly-braces to explicitly encapsulate your loops and if-else statements, otherwise only the subsequent statement will be a part of it.  For example:

```
if (condition)
    goto fail;
    goto fail;
```

Only the first `goto fail;` is a part of the if-statement; the second one is in actuality a separate entity even though it is indented as if it were a part of the if-statement.  (See this for a breakdown of the real-life bug in Apple code this example is based on: https://dwheeler.com/essays/apple-goto-fail.html )

So get your braces right and indenting right so the code does what it looks like it is doing.

Secondly, you're printing a newline between your logic that prints the first pyramid and second pyramid, so they could never exist side-by-side.  That newline is where you should be inserting that extra space character, not in the logic of your second pyramid.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int H;
    //Ask for Height of Pyramid
    do {
        H = get_int("Height Please: ");

    } while (H<=0 || H > 8);

    for(int x = 0; x < H; x++) {
        // Create left Aligned Pyramid
        for(int y = 0; y < H; y++) {
            if (x + y < H - 1) {
                printf(" ");
            }
            else {
                printf("#");
            }
        }

        printf(" ");    // With the curly braces and indentation fixed, we can clearly see this is not part of the logic of the first pyramid, but rather between the first and second pyramids where a space should be

        // Create Right Aligned Pyramid
        for(int y = 0; y < H; y++) {
            if (x - y >= 0) {
                printf("#");
                // remove the space character that did not belong here and was causing compile errors when you failed to use curly braces
            }
            else {
                printf(" ");
            }
        }

        printf("\n");   // Much easier to see where this logic comes into play with curly braces and indentation fixed.

    }
}
```

Sample output (hardcoded H=4):

```
   # #   
  ## ##  
 ### ### 
#### ####
```

Comment: @Yunnosch Okay, I passed a few options into indent that may have improved the indenting a little, and added sample output.

Comment: Better. Now it is just an indentation style that I am not a fan of, but it is now consistent and that is the only objective aspect to discuss. Matching my preferred style is nothing you need to bother about and should not be a reason for anybody for not upvoting. (I can't upvote again however... ;-) )